Lag when streaming music from AWS S3 and Cloudfront
I'm building a music streaming app and I have all the musics stored in a S3 bucket.
I also set up a CDN with Cloudfront.
The problem is that when I go on my deployed site and I play any music it lags (it takes multiple seconds to play one second) but when I play it from the dev environment it works perfectly (I'm using the same database and bucket between my dev environment and my deployed site).
I don't understand why there is a difference and what could be its origin.
